# How to scale two UV islands of different sizes to be an identical size?

Tags: modeling, uv, scale

How to scale two UV islands of different sizes to be an identical size?

I have UV unwrapped my model but want islands to be the same size as each other.

Comment: what's the problem if you scale them manually?

Comment: the complicated path is with a python script, if it is a single island, I would do it manually, if there were 50 islands I would think to invest time in a python script for an addon

Answer (score 3):

Select the geometry in *Edit Mode*, then in *UV Editor* select the islands (you can do it by hovering the mouse over the 1st island and pressing <kbd>L</kbd> then repeating for the 2nd island). Now in **UV** menu choose **Average Islands Scale**:

[image]

Neither island will rotate, however, they can move and, of course, scale. You may want to keep one of these islands in place (let's say because you already painted this area in Texture Paint mode). In this case I would just write down X distance between two arbitrary points A and B of the island I want to keep in place, as well as X and Y coordinates of point A, then average, then divide the new X distance between points A and B by the previous distance to get the ratio, by which I would scale the islands back so the "locked island" is again at its original scale. Finally, I would read the new X and Y coordinates of point A, so I know by how much to move the islands so it is back at its original coordinates:

[image]

Transcript of the GIF:

I chose points A and B in corners so it's easy to remember which they were after averaging the scale, then I copy-pasted the Y coordinate of A point to the Notepad, then I did that with X as well as pasted it to the Calculator. Then I copied the X coordinate of B point, pressed <kbd>-</kbd> in the Calculator, pasted the value, pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then copy-pasted the result to the Notepad. Then selected both islands with <kbd>L</kbd>, UV->Average Islands Scale, Repeated x-distance calculation, copied the result and in Blender pressed <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>/</kbd> for inverse (1/x). Selected A point, copy-pasted its coordinates to the Notepad. Moved the island a little bit in random direction to get the Move dialog, then pasted the coordinates in the form `Ax - new Ax` and `Ay - new Ay`, so this time Blender had to crunch the numbers instead of the Calculator. Done.

Of course if that's a recurring problem it would be sane to automate it in a Python script.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have 2 islands and you don't care how they are oriented, just choose the Normalize option in the UV's menu. That is what it's for.

But let's say you took your time manually unwrapping and arranging several islands and need to match the scale of both groups but don't want to ruin the work you already did.

1. select only the relevant faces in the model (faces you need to
   normalize). Make sure the option in the upper-left to link the model
   select to the UV layout is OFF.
2. You will see in the UV editor that only the selected faces are
   visible. This also means that operations in the UV editor will not affect hidden UVs.
   Choose from the menu in the UV editor to Normalize the UVs. Now all of those UVs are the same size. *This WILL reposition and CAN (unless you uncheck the option) rotate the islands though*, so if that is a problem you will need to rotate them back into position now.
3. Drag those faces over someplace where they will be together, but not intersect other UVs. Select all the faces on your model. You will see that all UVs are visible in the UV editor now. Manually scale the islands you just normalized to make sure all islands are perceptually the same size.

This way, you don't have to touch islands that are already the right size and in the right position.